# how to call a website from cmd using a non registered domain name?

Tags: networking, dns, cmd, ping

Usually When you ping a website (e.g Google.com) it replies with a specific IP
My question is: Is there anyway where you can call a website and replies with an IP you have set manually like 1.2.3.4

meaning if I ping google.com from my pc it will reply with 1.2.3.4

Comment: Firstly, this question is quite off topic. Secondly, you should probably read up on how IP addresses work before you go any further. You will probably answer your own question by then :)

Comment: Also, look at some info on DNS Resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding the domain and IP to your host file. What OS are you running?

On Windows Server 2012 you will find the host file on `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc`

Add your domain and IP like this

`64.49.219.194 www.domain.com`

Try ping again.

Comment: I am running windows server 2012. Could you be more specific.Thanx

Comment: See the edit on my answer. Hope it helps, for more info go to http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file